# Converting a Tumblr theme to a Blogger template

Tags: tumblr, blogger, tumblr-themes, blogger-themes

I really like [this](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/475) theme, and I'd like to use the Blogger platform rather than Tumblr.

While Tumblr's theme are relatively easy to understand, trying to make sense of all the stuff that's going on in Blogger has proved difficult.

Is there a step-by-step guide somewhere on how to convert an existing Tumblr theme to be used at Blogger?

Comment: Hey daniel did you find out any solution for this?

Comment: @KishorNanda: I'm afraid not. I ended up rolling my own blog from scratch using a static generator.

Comment: that sounds great! can you recommend me a static generator?

Comment: @KishorNanda: there are plenty out there. As a python user I went with [hyde](http://hyde.github.com/), another popular one in ruby is [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

Comment: @daniel.jackson Could you place your solution as an answer. I don't think there is anything out there that is the silver bullet for this process.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of weeks of looking around, it seems there's no step-by-step guide or something similar to do this.

Instead I ended up rolling my own blog from scratch using a static generator called [hyde](http://hyde.github.com/).